# How to set current value for RangeSeekBar without changing Minimum value?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm using [https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar](http://RangeSeekBar) to implement a two way seekbar functionality. I have set my initial range values, for example:

Min: 0

Max: 5000

I want the min, max value to be same, but when I start the activity the seek bar should be dragged to a value, say 20.

If I use setSelectedMinValue() method, my Min value is being overridden to 20.

How do I solve this?

My Code:

```
RangeSeekBar<Integer> rangebar   = (RangeSeekBar<Integer>)findViewById(R.id.rb); 

rangebar.setRangeValues(0, 5000);
```

OnSeekBar Dragged:

```
rangebar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {


                @Override
                public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {

                    // Binding values to textviews below Seekbar 
                    tvMin.setText(""+minValue);
                    tvMax.setText(""+maxValue);


                }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show me your code, what exactly you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Maximum and progress value here and your Min value will be 0

```
seek.setMax(100);
seek.setProgress(20);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min" + seek.getX(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party code, it doesn't have setProgress method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
setSelected(true);//add this first.
setSelectedMinValue(you_onstart_activiy_min_value);//then set min value.
setSelectedMaxValue(your_onstart_activity_max_value);//you can set max vlaue.
bounds values (min and max) will not change.
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.